# звонки через gsm модем c компьютера

Tags: веб-программирование

Не могли бы Вы мне подсказать технологию, позволяющую совершать звонки через компьютер с подключенным к нему GSM модемом?

Answer (score 4):

Не давно занимался этим вопросом. Требовалось реализовать звонки из браузера на сотовые/стационарные телефона и прием входящих звонков. Если вам нужно примерно тоже самое, то ниже план действий

Первое, что нужно, это **сервер**. Он будет принимать VoIP трафик и обрабатывать его, передавать дальше. Я использовал `asterisk 13.08` в качестве сервера, хотя можно и `freeswitch` попробовать.

Что бы ваш `gsm модем` мог общаться с `asterisk-ом` необходимо [подключить и настроить](http://linux.mixed-spb.ru/asterisk/dongle_part1.php) модуль для работы с модемом (а так же и модем настроить, потому что изначально он не работает так как нужно )

Если ваша цель звонить из какого-нить приложения с компьютера (`X-lite`, другой софт фон), то на этом работа завершена. Настроить `dialplan`, пользователя и можно звонить.

Если же вам нужны именно звонки из браузера, идем дальше
Необходим изначально настроить `asterisk` на работу с `web-socket`, это не сложно, ибо в последних версиях `web-socket-ы` в `asterisk` уже есть.
На клиентской стороне, нам так же потребуется библиотека для звонков ( использовал [эту](https://github.com/DoubangoTelecom/sipml5) )

---

Ниже приведен более полный план по настройке всего этого добра, файлы конфигураций к сожалению не могу прикрепить, поэтому их придется найти самому

Ставил на `Ubuntu Server 14+ версии`

**Скачать asterisk**

```
wget http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk/asterisk-12-current.tar.gz
tar -zxvf asterisk-13-current.tar.gz
```

**Скачать зависимости**

```
cd asterisk-13.x.x/contrib/scripts/
./install_prereq install
```

**Скачать libsrtp (v1.5.4)**

```
git clone https://github.com/cisco/libsrtp.git
git checkout v1.5.4
```

**Установить пакет libsrtp**

```
./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC
make libsrtp.a
make uninstall
make install
ldconfig
```

**Скачать pjproject**

```
git clone https://github.com/asterisk/pjproject.git
```

**Установить пакет**

```
./configure --enable-shared --with-external-speex --with-external-gsm --with-external-srtp --disable-sound --disable-resample
make
make install
ldconfig
```

**Установить asterisk**

```
cd asterisk-13.x.x
./configure
make menuselect
```

в меню надо проверить есть ли звездочки

```
Channel Drivers -> chan_pjsip и chan_sip
Resource Modules -> res_srtp, res_crypto и res_http_websocket

make
make install
make samples
```

**Сгенерировать сертификаты**

```
mkdir /etc/asterisk/keys
cd /usr/src/asterisk-12.5.0/contrib/scripts/
./ast_tls_cert -C domain -O "ATC Design" -d /etc/asterisk/keys
```

Еще нужен ssl сертификат
Настроить файл конфигурации asterisk-a

**Скачать dongle**

```
wget https://github.com/oleg-krv/asterisk-chan-dongle/archive/asterisk13.zip
unzip asterisk13.zip
```

**Установить модуль**

```
В директории модуля:
    aclocal
    autoconf
    automake -a
    ./configure
    make 
    make install
```

После выполнения команды `make install`: убедитесь в том, что в каталог модулей asterisk скопирован модуль
`chan_dongle.so`. 

Каталог модулей `asterisk` по умолчанию находится здесь: `/usr/lib/asterisk/modules` . 
Если там нет файла `chan_dongle.so`, найдите его в папке с исходными кодами `chan_dongle` и скопируйте к модулям `asterisk` вручную.

Убедитесь в том, что в каталог конфигурации `asterisk` скопирован файл `dongle.conf`. По умолчанию каталог конфигурации `asterisk` находится здесь: `/etc/asterisk` . Если там этого файла нет, скопируйте его из папки с исходными кодами `chan_dongle` (подпапка etc) вручную.

Вот как то так)

Comment: Вы мой спаситель!!!))))

Comment: Тоже по такой схеме делал сервис. Скажите, а зачем вы используете SIP и PJSIP одновременно? Они не конфликтуют у Вас?

Comment: @carapuz https://habrahabr.ru/post/236291/#comment_7952643
Мой ответ - это солянка из статей на хабре и с других сайтов + какие-то свои грабли. Решил не рисковать, раз все работало без ошибок